# I want to change protocol from http to https in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, https

*Hello friends I am working on web application and i want to change protocol from http to https.I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express Web. I changed web server to **Use IIS Express** then i selected enable ssl true from properties frame and checked applicationhost file i found

```
   <site name="Texniki Tapsiriq" id="13">
     <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Texniki Tapsiriq\Texniki Tapsiriq\Texniki Tapsiriq" />
            </application>
            <application path="/Login.aspx" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Texniki Tapsiriq\Texniki Tapsiriq\Texniki Tapsiriq" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54650:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44301:localhost" />

            </bindings>
        </site>
```

https protocol added* but when i try to debug it i get error such as page not found or name is changed How can I fix it ?

Comment: `What should I do?` change it from `http` to `https`

Answer (score 0):

[Reference code project (Matt Sollars)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7206/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically-Ver)

```
<secureWebPages>
    <files>
        <add path="Default.aspx" secure="Insecure" />

        <add path="Admin/MoreAdminStuff.aspx" secure="Ignore" />

        <add path="Legal/Copyright.aspx" secure="Ignore" />

        <add path="Lib/PopupCalendar.aspx" secure="Ignore" />

    </files>
    <directories>
        <add path="/" recurse="False" />

        <add path="Admin" />

        <add path="Admin/Info" secure="Insecure" />
        <add path="Members/Secure" recurse="True" />

    </directories>

</secureWebPages>
```